# Auth0 JWT java library throws error random times

Tags: java, jwt, auth0

We are using auth0 java library for JWT generation and validation. The problem is it throws exceptions for the same string at random times. I am not exactly sure what is causing this issue. Below is my code-

```
final static String secret = "some random key";
    final static JWTSigner signer = new JWTSigner(secret);
    final static JWTVerifier verifier = new JWTVerifier(secret);

public String gen(UUID id) {
    final long iat = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000l; // issued at claim
    final HashMap<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    claims.put("id", id.toString());
    claims.put("iat", iat);

    final String jwt = signer.sign(claims);

    return jwt;
}

/** This method checks Bearer <jwt> and <jwt> both type of tokens */
protected UUID authenticate(String jwt) {
    UUID userId = null;
    try {
        try { // Getting the token

        String[] ar = jwt.split(Constants.WHITE_SPACE);
        final Map<String, Object> claims = verifier.verify(ar[1].trim());
        userId = UUID.fromString((String) claims.get("id"));

     } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aie) {

        final Map<String, Object> claims = verifier.verify(jwt.trim());
        userId = UUID.fromString((String) claims.get("id"));
        }

    return userId;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Not a valid JWT string:" + jwt, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works sometimes, and sometimes it throws random errors. Like

```
Not a valid JWT string:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0NzM4NTE5NjQsImlkIjoiMmMwMTBiNTAtODhiNC00NWMxLWI4OGItOGY2ZDNmMzFkZjdlIn0.CHRsJxuTZe7y1VQikP9a0_-nWVA-TMundam506VTGx4 
com.auth0.jwt.internal.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected close marker ']': expected '}' (for ROOT starting at [Source: java.io.StringReader@11c289a2; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@11c289a2; line: 1, column: 2]

Not a valid JWT string:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0NzM4NTE5NjQsImlkIjoiMmMwMTBiNTAtODhiNC00NWMxLWI4OGItOGY2ZDNmMzFkZjdlIn0.CHRsJxuTZe7y1VQikP9a0_-nWVA-TMundam506VTGx4
com.auth0.jwt.internal.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

Are we missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, we switched to another library and so far we didn't face any issue.

```
    <!-- JWT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @theGablerRises, could you please share what version did you use when encountered the problem? We are having the same problem. exception is thrown what seems to be at random. However it works fine in browser, and works with randomly timed exception when pages accessed with hybrid app.

Comment: I am sorry man. I don't have access to that project anymore and I don't remember version. :-(